# How to merge embedded array with array in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have arrays and nested arrays, such that:

```
a = [1,2]
b = [[3,4],[5,6]]
c = [7,8]
```

What's the best way to create

```
d = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]]
```

in Ruby?

UPDATE:

The goal is to create a method below:

```
def foo([a,b,c])
  --some logic that iterates through each array--
end
```

Comment: Simplest would be `[a] + b + [c]`, but I believe you need more general solution?

Comment: Yes please.  I will add to the original post.

Comment: Need some more clarification - what is to happen if for example `a = [1]` or `a = [[1,2], 'hello']`

Comment: Why the rush to select an answer?  Consider waiting awhile in future.  A quick selection tends to discourage additional, possibly better, answers.

Comment: Cary, thanks, I'm just realizing that now :).  This is the first time a question I raised has actually elicited more than one response.  Definitely have learned my lesson.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def foo(xss)
  xss.flat_map { |xs| xs.first.is_a?(Array) ? xs : [xs] }
en

foo([a, b, c]) #=> [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]]
```

Comment: Probably the best solution, flat_map is way faster than most of the other methods out there.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do :

```
a = [1,2]
b = [[3,4],[5,6]]
c = [7,8]

final_ary = [a,b,c].inject([]) do |out_ary,ary| 
  if ary.first.is_a?(Array)
    out_ary.concat(ary)
  else
    out_ary.push(ary)
  end
end

final_ary
# => [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]]
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work assuming inputs are always arrays. Might have some side effects if any input is formatted differently.

```
def foo(*args)
  args.map {|a| a.first.is_a?(Array) ? a : [a]}.inject([], :+)
end

foo([1,2], [[3,4],[5,6]], [7,8])    #=>  [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]]
```

Comment: Thank you!  I will accept this answer because it is a bit more readable then Arup's.  Optional question to you:  is there a way to implement something like [a, b.each{|b| b}, c]?

Comment: I hadn't seen this, which is basically my answer. Note though that you shouldn't concat arrays using inject, it's very inefficient O(n^2). Use flat_map instead.

Comment: @tokland - Could you explain - I always thought inject is O(n). Is array addition O(n) as well or am I missing sth else?

Comment: Enumerble#inject is O(n) but the inner operation Array#+ is also O(n), so the total is O(n^2). That's because Array#+ creates a new array. With an in-place update, it would be O(n): xss.reduce([], :concat).

Answer (score 1):

```
def foo(a,b,c)
  final = []

  a.first.is_a?(Array) ? a.each { |x| final << x } : final << a
  b.first.is_a?(Array) ? b.each { |x| final << x } : final << b
  c.first.is_a?(Array) ? c.each { |x| final << x } : final << c

  final
end
```

Comment: Perhaps you could add a little explanation as to how this should solve the problem, rather than just posting some code?

Answer (score 1):

```
def foo (*args)
  args.flatten.each_slice(2).to_a
end

foo(a,b,c) # => [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]]
```

Comment: If `b` is `b = [[3,4],[5,6,7]]` ?  :-)

Comment: No.. problem.. Go ahead :-)

Answer (score 0):

A general solution:

```
def extract(arr, result=[])
  return result if arr.empty?
  arr.each {|e| (e.first.is_a? Array) ? result=extract(e,result) : result << e}
end

p extract( [ [1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7] ] )
  #=> [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7]]
p extract( [ [1,2],[ [3,4],[5,6] ],[7,8]] )
  #=> [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]] 
p extract( [ [1,2],[ [3,4],[ [5,6],[7,8] ] ],[9,10,11] ] )
  #=> [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10, 11]]
p extract( [ [1,2],[ [3,4],[ [5,6],[ [7,8],[9,10] ] ] ],[11,12] ])
  #=> [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10], [11, 12]]
```